# Groovy Implicit Library Loading without Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I have the following in my groovy script in jenkins

```
#!groovy
@Library('my-library') _
```

And in Jenkins I have this `my-library` implicitly loaded as a [global pipeline library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries).

I want to be able to run this groovy script on my local machine using `groovy script.groovy`, but I get the following error.

```
unable to resolve class Library ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 2, column 1.
   @Library('my-library') _
   ^
1 error
```

How can I get this to run locally? I am incredibly new to Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce a JAR of the library using `gradle build` and move it to `$HOME/.groovy/lib`

I could then call the class from my groovy script normally. I had to remove the @Library() reference though since it was failing.